# replicate-do-table unable to start slave mysql

Tags: mysql, replication, slave

I have problems starting slave server when I add replicate-do-table. Current config that works:

```
server-id=2
master-host=10.100.27.99
master-user=slejv
master-password=<pass>
master-connect-retry=60
replicate-do-db=piksearch
```

Config that doesn't work:

```
server-id=2
master-host=10.100.27.99
master-user=slejv
master-password=<pass>
master-connect-retry=60
replicate-do-db=piksearch
replicate-do-table=artikli
replicate-do-table=artikli_polja
replicate-do-table=artikli_posjete8
replicate-do-table=artikli_view
replicate-do-table=kategorije
replicate-do-table=online
replicate-do-table=pitanje_artikal
replicate-do-table=polja
```

> server02:/etc/mysql# /etc/init.d/mysql restart
>   Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld.
>   Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!

Comment: Have you tried 'db.table' instead of just 'table'? So 'piksearch.artikli', for example.

Answer (score 9):

see this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-table):

`replicate-do-db` is  in contrast to `replicate-do-table`

you must remove:

```
replicate-do-db=piksearch
replicate-do-table=artikli
replicate-do-table=artikli_polja
replicate-do-table=artikli_posjete8
replicate-do-table=artikli_view
replicate-do-table=kategorije
replicate-do-table=online
replicate-do-table=pitanje_artikal
replicate-do-table=polja
```

and write:

```
replicate-do-table=piksearch.artikli
replicate-do-table=piksearch.artikli_polja
...
```